# How to use incremental static regeneration in nextjs 13?

Tags: next.js, next.js13, react-server-components

Whenever I run `npm run build` and `npm run start`, the posts list doesn't get updated whenever I add new post in the backend. I am new to nextjs 13.

```
async function getPosts() {
  try {
    const getData = await fetch(`${process.env.MY_SITE}/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, {
      next: {
        revalidate: 20,
      },
    });

    const data = await getData.json();
    return data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This is my code. NextJS revalidation is not working in production Mode. (It works fine whenever the revalidation is set to zero but it's not working for revalidation of 20 seconds.)

```
export default async function Home() {
  const posts = await getPosts();
  return (
    <main className="p-10">
      <h1 className="text-4xl">Posts</h1>
      <br />
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
        {posts.map((post: any) => {
          return (
            <Link
              href={`/posts/${post.id}`}
              key={post.id}
              className="border-2 border-gray-500 p-4 rounded-xl"
            >
              <h2 className="text-xl font-semibold">{post.title.rendered}</h2>
              <div
                className="text-gray-300"
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: post.content.rendered }}
              />
            </Link>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Comment: Are you waiting at least 20 seconds in between refreshes to see the new content appear?

Comment: having a similar problem, only the 'no-cache' option is flushing the cache locally, but apparently the deployed website has flushed the cache.